# help building best query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table structure that is basically

Sent_txts_parent
Sent_txts_control_parent
Sent_txts_control_child

the link together as

Sent_txts_parent = top level

Sent_txts_control_parent link to Sent_txts_parent via
Sent_txts_control_parent.parent_id = Sent_txts_parent.id

Sent_txts_control_child links to Sent_txts_control_parent via
Sent_txts_control_child.parent_id = Sent_txts_control_parent.id

I need to run a query which when given a `Sent_txts_parent.id` needs to return all rows from `Sent_txts_control_child` which are linked to that ID.

What would be the best way to do this query?

Possibly something like

```
Select stcc.* from Sent_txts_control_child stcc
left join Sent_txts_control_parent stcp
on stcc.parent_id = stcp.id
left join Sent_txts_parent stp
on stp.parent_id = stcp.parent_id;
```

But I dont even know if I have my joins o the right side, nor if that is the most optimized.

Comment: a little goggling on *JOIN* will find your answer

Comment: If you can post your table definitions, I can help you with the query as well as some references/research material

Comment: Btw @Dagon, I dont thing _goggling_ will help much ;) google however, I have done so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason to be using outer joins.  The simple solution is:

```
SELECT cc.*
  FROM Sent_txts_control_child  AS cc
  JOIN Sent_txts_control_parent AS cp ON cc.Parent_ID = cp.ID
  JOIN Sent_txts_parent         AS st ON cp.Parent_ID = st.ID
 WHERE st.ID = ?;
```

However, we can observe that the value you are given corresponds to Sent_txts_parent.ID also matches Sent_txts_control_parent.Parent_ID, so there is no need for the triple-join; we can use a double-join instead:

```
SELECT cc.*
  FROM Sent_txts_control_child  AS cc
  JOIN Sent_txts_control_parent AS cp ON cc.Parent_ID = cp.ID
 WHERE cp.Parent_ID = ?;
```

The question mark represents the value that you are searching for.